# Multiple actions in one trigger, not work

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

guys!
I want multiple actions in one trigger but it's not working.
Can someone help?
Where is the problem?
Where is my mistake?
Please help.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `usertrigger` ;

CREATE DEFINER =  `cmsbalti`@`localhost` TRIGGER `usertrigger`  
    BEFORE DELETE ON  `users`          
    FOR EACH ROW  
  INSERT INTO  `del_users` (fullname) 
  VALUES (old.fullname)

BEFORE INSERT ON `del_users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM `gallery`
   WHERE uid = old.id;
END
```

Thank you.

Comment: First thing is first: exactly what do you want your actions in the trigger to do and when do you want your trigger to run?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for this i would not use triggers !! just alter your design and add a `ON UPDATE CASCADE` constraint ,so only one action will be needed as the constraint will do the rest. Check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) for more details.

---

**As for the trigger option**

Only one  action trigger is possible.
**To make it easy to understand see example :**

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE actor(
  actor_id SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   last_update TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (actor_id),
  INDEX idx_actor_last_name (last_name)
 );
```

**Create first trigger :**

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql>
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
    -> AFTER INSERT
    -> ON actor
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   -- code
    -> END
    -> $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

**Create second trigger :**

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER trigger2
    -> AFTER UPDATE
    -> ON actor
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   -- code
    -> END
    -> $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

**Create third action triger :**

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER trigger3
    -> AFTER DELETE
    -> ON actor
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   -- code
    -> END
    -> $$
DELIMITER ;Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

**Now let's try to create a fort trigger with the same action as the first trigger**

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER trigger11
    -> AFTER INSERT
    -> ON actor
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   -- code
    -> END
    -> $$
ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'
```

**So end of story - you cannot create the trigger the way you have written it - make two different triggers as the evens are different.**

So my advice is to create two triggers on that table and make sure to put them in block to avoid problems at execution level (very little chance).

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't scatter the logic of deleting a user across several triggers. It will make it much harder to maintain.
2. Just use `BEGIN ... END` block in your `DELETE` trigger and do both insert an audit record in `del_users` and delete related records from `gallery`. *Don't forget to change `DELIMITER` in mysql client.*
3. If you're using foreign key constraints you'll have to opt out to `BEFORE` event for your trigger because you have to delete child records prior to deleting a parent.

That being said your trigger might look like

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ad_users 
BEFORE DELETE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO del_users (user_id, fullname, deleted)
  VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.fullname, NOW());
  DELETE FROM gallery 
   WHERE uid = OLD.id;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1941b/1)** demo